# Flutter "flutter_launcher_icons 0.9.3" android icon now working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

i am using flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.3" for our app icon "android", but icon is not working.

1. pubsepc.yaml

```
name: tg_rewards_flutter
version: 1.6.0+6
publish_to: none
description: A new Flutter project.
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.2.0"

dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  carousel_nullsafety: ^0.1.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  flip_card: ^0.6.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.1.0
  form_field_validator: ^1.1.0
  get: ^4.6.5
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  http: ^0.13.4
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.3"
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  lints: 1.0.1

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icon/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/carousel/
```

after this i am running below command

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

[image: command result]

android project icons

[image: Icons]

App Icon

[image: App Icon]

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of icons required for adaptive and normal icons.

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces adaptive launcher icons, which can display a variety of shapes across different device models.

If your device version is above 8, it'll use the adaptive icon, and since you have not provided any, it'll just use the Android logo.

You can use something like this:

```
flutter_icons:
    ios: true
    android: true
    image_path_ios: "assets/app_icon/app_icon_with_white_background.png"
    image_path_android: "assets/app_icon/app_icon.png"
    adaptive_icon_background: "assets/app_icon/white_background.png"
    adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/app_icon/app_icon_forground.png"
```

Comment: flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/icon/icon.png"

  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true

but still same result

Comment: You can't just give the same image there and expect it to work. You can refer this: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Comment: You'll also need a plain white image (if you prefer) as your icon background it is also used in adaptive icons in some launchers. Create a plain white image asset, in my case I've had 2048x2048px white image